# java printWrite writes nothing to file, but file is created

Tags: java, file

i use this to write string to file.
I see this file has been created by this code but no content inside.

```
PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter("/home/paul/Documents/linuxwork/core_java/Welcome/src/output.txt");
out.println("helloworld");
```

Did I miss anything?

THanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Automatic line flushing is disabled with [the constructor you used](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/PrintWriter.html#PrintWriter(java.io.File)), so you need to call `out.flush()` to flush the stream to the file:

```java
PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter("/home/paul/Documents/linuxwork/core_java/Welcome/src/output.txt");
out.println("helloworld");
out.flush();
```

Answer (score 1):

Possibly your missing close()

```
PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter("/home/paul/Documents/linuxwork/core_java/Welcome/src/output.txt");
out.println("helloworld");
out.close();//<-- added this
```

Comment: plus one for just "close". You should close streams anyway and it includes the final "flush". So you can do without "flush", but better not without "close".

Comment: if i don't close, in java, will that cause memory leak or something?